# Replicated container of Certificate Authority (CA) server is not working

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, high-availability, docker-container, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to Maintain the High Availability (HA) of the Certificate Authority (CA) server (Without using the Container orchestration Technique like K8). To achieve that, I used the YAML anchor and merge syntax. Both containers run and listen to the server port.
The Problem here arises is, Only one server works as expected as previous as a normal, and another replicated using merge and anchor is not working. It throws an error while sending a request to the replicated server using SDK.
I performed enrollAdmin operation using enrollAdmin.js provided by fabcar (sample provided by hyperledger fabric). The error code is as below :

```
gopal@gopal:~/Dappdev/first/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript$ node enrollAdmin.js 
Wallet path: /home/gopal/Dappdev/first/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/wallet
Enroll the admin user, and import the new identity into the wallet
2021-01-12T08:42:03.572Z - error: [FabricCAClientService.js]: Failed to enroll admin, error:%o message=Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: write EPROTO 139961596319552:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
], stack=Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: write EPROTO 139961596319552:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
]
    at ClientRequest.request.on (/home/gopal/Dappdev/first/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAClient.js:487:12)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:107:12)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:436:5)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:461:5)
    at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:49:7)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._destroy (net.js:614:3)
    at TLSSocket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:37:8)
Failed to enroll admin user "admin": Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: write EPROTO 139961596319552:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
]
gopal@gopal:~/Dappdev/first/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript$
```

Additionally, to explain more, I am adding CA configuration file as below.

```
version: '2'
networks:
  byfn:
services:
  ca0: &name-me
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/key.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/key.pem -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_server01
    networks:
      - byfn

# Replicated CA
  ca01:
    <<: *name-me  # <- this is a merge (<<) with an alias (*name-me)
    # keys below merge notation override those that declared under anchor
    # so this:
    ports:
    - "8054:8054"
    container_name: ca_server02
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=8054
```

Further more, to confirm the configuration, I have added a connection profile for this CA.

```
"certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:8054",
            "caName": "ca-org1",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nh4zC6aHdSt2u4hJtXLB+8JNzVy8=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
```

> Is there a better way to solve this issue of replicated docker container not working for CA server replication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above problem of not working of replicated container of CA server is solved by adding the environment variable on replicated container as below :

```
services:
  ca0: &name-me
  #ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/key.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/key.pem -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_server01
    networks:
      - byfn

# Replicated CA
  ca01:
    <<: *name-me  # <- this is a merge (<<) with an alias (*name-me)
    # keys below merge notation override those that declared under anchor
    # so this:
    ports:
    - "8054:8054"
    container_name: ca_server02
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/key.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=8054
```

In this way, replicated container of CA server works.